# QML - Dynamically create Timers when event occurs

Tags: javascript, qt, dynamic, qml

I have a ListView whose delegate is a red button. When button's color changes, I want the program to dynamically create a timer (which is specific for that delegate), which sets again the color to red after 5 seconds. Then I want the program to destroy the timer. How can I do it?

Here is my actual code:

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    model: myListModel
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.leftMargin: 20; anchors.rightMargin: 20
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    clip: true
    spacing: 8
    delegate: Button {
        id: myDelegate
        property int myDelegateIndex: index + 1
        width: 100; height: 50
        text: "Push"
        background: Rectangle {
            id: myDelegateBackground
            color: "red"
            onColorChanged: {
                myTimer.start();
            }
        }

        Timer {
            id: myTimer
            interval: 5000
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: {
               myDelegateBackground.color = "red";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all a lot!!!

Comment: why do you want to destroy the Timer after using it? why not have "repeat" property set to false, and then it will only be triggered once. also set "running" to false, so that it doesn't start until you press the button. The Timer component will be destroyed when the delegate is destroyed, you do not need to do it manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a Component

**SelfdestroyingTimer.qml**

```
Timer {
    property var action // Assing a function to this, that will be executed
    running: true
    onTriggered: {
        action()
        this.destroy() // If this timer is dynamically instantitated it will be destroyed when triggered
    }
}
```

And have a function:

```
function createOneShotTimer(duration, action) {
    var comp = Qt.createComponent('SelfdestroyingTimer.qml')
    comp.createObject(root,  { action: action, interval: duration })
}
```

Or declare the Component in the same file (so you do not need to create it each time you want an instance), and it looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Component {
        id: singleShot
        Timer {
            property var action
            running: true
            onTriggered: {
                if (action) action() // To check, whether it is a function, would be better.
                this.destroy()
            }
            // This proves, it will be destroyed.
            Component.onDestruction: console.log('Timer says bye bye!')
        }
    }


    Button {
        onClicked: {
            singleShot.createObject(this, { action: function() { console.log('ACTION!!!') }, interval: 2000 })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the sense of 'action'? Is it a parameter for deciding timer's lifetime? How do I associate the just-created-timer to my button delegate? @derM

Comment: Whilst it is good to show people new techniques, it is dangerous to encourage the dynamic creation of objects from within a delegate. If the ListView is scrolled so that it starts to destroy delegates which have gone out of view, then dynamic objects can be left with no valid QML context and cause segfaults.

Comment: @MarkCh, you are wrong. Dynamic creation of objects is totaly safe, if done right, even when done from within a delegate. The only thing that is important is, that you set a parent, and this parent will not outlast the delegate. So if you set it to be the delegate or any of it's children, the object will be destroyed at the latest, when it's parent is destroyed, but you can also control the lifetime yourself.

Comment: If however you chose to set the parent to `root` and `root` is outside of the delegates, the dynamically created object will not be destroyed when the delegate leaves the view. More dangerous is to set the parent to be `null` as then the garbage collector will take care of the destruction and he usually fails in counting references. So it is most likely to be destroyed before you want it.

Comment: @derM both solutions work for me. However, my main problem is how to REFRESH the listview. The first times, in fact, the color is updated. After a while, it is not. How can I FORCE THE REFRESH?? Thank you!

Comment: Could you update your question, to include the code that does not refresh your color? For me, it does, so I can't replicate your problem.

Comment: @Elena I don't understand the question either. ListView can't be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

There would appear to be no need to dynamically create timers. Create one Timer for each delegate and reuse it by calling restart().

See example below:

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    model: 20
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.leftMargin: 20; anchors.rightMargin: 20
    orientation: Qt.Vertical
    clip: true
    spacing: 8
    delegate: Button {
        id: myDelegate
        property int myDelegateIndex: index + 1
        width: 100; height: 50
        text: "Push"
        background: Rectangle {
            id: myDelegateBackground
            color: "red"
            onColorChanged: {
                myTimer.restart();
            }

            Timer {
                id: myTimer
                interval: 5000
                running: false
                repeat: false
                onTriggered: {
                   myDelegateBackground.color = "red";
                }
            }
        }
        onClicked: {
            background.color = "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

Regardless of what mechanism you choose to do this, you will have problems caused by the ListView destroying delegates which scroll out of the visible region of the ListView. When a delegate gets destroyed and recreated, it will have its original color and the timer will be in its default state.

There are two options to deal with this scenario:

- Save the state of the delegates to a list (in a javascript var) outside the scope of the delegate.
- Increase the Listview cacheBuffer so that the ListView does not destroy the delegates when they go out of the visible region.

Comment: Your assumption "Regardless of what mechanism you choose to do this, you will have problems caused by the ListView destroying delegates which scroll out of the visible region of the ListView. When a delegate gets destroyed and recreated, it will have its original color and the timer will be in its default state." is wrong. Especially when having tons of delegates, it is encouraged to lazily instantiate parts of them that are not necessarily needed for every delegate. Timers are small though, but in mass they can become very relevant.